# Only displaying top 3 bars in a ggplot2 chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I am trying to figure out a way to display only the top three bars of a data set. In order to make things simple, I'm using the diamond data set to illustrate what I'd like to do. First, I ordered it by largest to smallest.

```
library(data.table)
diamonds <- data.table(diamonds)
diamonds1 <- within(diamonds, cut <- factor(cut, levels=names(sort(table(cut), decreasing=TRUE))))
```

Then, I plotted.

```
ggplot(diamonds1, aes(cut, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position="dodge") + guides(fill=FALSE) + ylab("Count") + xlab("Cut")
```

And I got this:

[image: My plot]

But instead of seeing all of the bars, I just want to see the top three. Additionally, I want this to be repeatable, so if the data set changes and there is a different top three, I can use the same code to create the correct top three. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm using data.table for all data manipulation, so if there is a solution that has to be done within the data before graphing, I'd prefer it to use data.table. Thus, the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can define `xlim()`. Add:

```
+ xlim('Ideal', 'Premium', 'Very Good')
```

**Edit** after @Arun comments below: A more direct approach would be to subset the data before you feed it to `ggplot()`. You can use `data.table`'s features to make this very fast

```
setkey(diamonds, cut)  ## needed for fast subsetting and grouping
tt <- diamonds[, list(count=.N), by=cut]  ## same as table(diamonds$cut) but faster    
cut.values <- tt[order(count), cut][1:3]  ## select top 3 cut values by count
ggplot(diamonds[J(cut.values)], ...       ## run the same plot commands on subset of data
```

Comment: I added a note to my original post, but I'm looking for a way to do it so that I can automate it in the future. I'm not guaranteed that Ideal, Premium, and Very Good will always be the top three, so I want to have a solution that will always give me the top three.

Comment: I am guessing you want the top 3 by frequency (the tallest 3 bars). In that case you can extract them using `names(sort(table(cut), decreasing=TRUE)[1:3])`

Comment: When I do that, it also gives me a bar saying NA. Any advice as to where to go from there?

Comment: What does `names(sort(table(cut), decreasing=TRUE)[1:3])` return? No idea why that would return NAs.

Comment: @Arun thanks for the tip. I have a good grasp of the functions. I meant why they would return it in this case. If there are more than 3 levels this should return exactly what the OP was looking for. I tested it with simulated data just to be sure.

Comment: Either would work fine. I ended up getting it to work by doing exactly what you said and then adding in `[cut != "NA"]` and then plotting.

Comment: @Arun I thought he may not want the whole data subsetted, but thinking of it I recall that the `scale_` functions in `ggplot2` do exactly that. Perhaps OP should feed it a smaller data.table. I will modify my answer to suggest that. Thanks.